# Error in saving while uploading android apk in google play console

Tags: google-play-console

I'm trying to upload a new android apk in the google play console. It has a couple of additional permissions like READ_SMS which is triggering a permissions form that I have filled too. I am however unable to save the data. Error code in logs: 858285013

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Uin.png)

Comment: Looks like a server error. Only the Play Console support team will be able to help you

Comment: We are also facing same issue, did you find the root cause for it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in one of my apps. I followed the below steps to resolve the issue.

> - Upload the new apk with only required permissions in the track which you want
> - Now you can see the Old apk with retain option
> - If you click on retain button, you will see permission declaration form
> - Select **No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permission policy** option and click on save in bottom right of the page
> - Now click on discard button
> - Now create new release and upload the latest APK and fill the declaration form
> - Save the new changes and now you will able to save the changes

Before that if your app is using RECEIVE_SMS & SEND_SMS to verify the mobile number, then you need to change the implementation of mobile verification. For that you need to use Google's [SMS retriver API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview). If your app comply with the Google developer policy, then you can keep the READ_SMS permission and for that you need to mention the valid reason in the permission declaration form in play console. Or you can remove the READ_SMS permission, and proceed with the flow as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You must Use SMS intent or you need to send a declaration Form... SMS, CALL LOG.. not allowed from 2019 Jan 9th.. Plesse Check this link android SMS Permissions

[SMS Permission Declaration Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Comment: For SMS Autoread like OTP , we have to use https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />    
   
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />  
        
Automatically-read-OTP from SMSes in later versions from api level 26 is not allowed from 2019 Jan 9th?